# How to logout user from Quarkus + Primefaces web app?

Tags: primefaces, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

From [this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oidc-code-flow-authentication-concept) logging out user should be achieved by calling endpoint registered as *quarkus.oidc.logout.path*. I have this line in the application.properties:

`quarkus.oidc.logout.path=/secure/logout`

However, When I try to call it by clicking on the link like this:

`<a href="/secure/logout"> <i class="pi pi-arrow-left"/> </a>`

I'm getting 404 Resource not found. How to make it work?

Also tried to use *quarkus.oidc.logout.frontchannel.path* -  getting the same 404.

UPDATE: I can't reproduce it with Quarkus 3.2.0.Final, so its not an issue/question anymore:)

Comment: Have you verified by hovering the link that the correct URL is generated for `/source/logout` that it is taking you to the expected logout URL?

Comment: Yes. This can be reproduced here https://dev.collarclubvernon.ca - login with google or with freya:prime, click on user icon and hover over 'Log Out'. The link is https://dev.collarclubvernon.ca/secure/logout which should be right.